# Is Standard PriceBook available for adding to an Opportunity?

Tags: opportunity, pricebook

Simply the title is the question. Somewhere I have read that the standard pricebook is the list of all products with their associated prices and this can't be attached to an opportunity. If you need a pricebook with all products you need to create a custom pricebook with all products.

But in our org the standard pricebook is available in the dropdown list when trying to attache a pricebook into an opportunity. Standard pricebook is in **Active** state. Is this the normal behavior?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**. You can add Products via Standard Price Book to your Opportunity.

*To include products on an opportunity, quote, or order, you must first choose a price book that contains the products you want to add.*

*Click Choose Price Book in the Products related list on an opportunity or the Quote Line Items related list on a quote to select a price book. This button appears when you have access to more than one price book*

this could be either Standard or Custom price book

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=products_pricebook.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. In the documentation it's not specifying anything related the availability of Standard pricebook for attaching to an Opportunity is it?

Comment: there is no direct statement saying you can only choose custom or only standard price book. what it says is as long as you have access to a price book, you should be able to select products from it. - think of orgs which doesn't create custom price books , they can select products form standard price books :-)

Comment: The standard price book *can* be deactivated, though, and if someone has done that in the user's org, that would explain why there's some confusion. They should check to see if the book is active, and if not, activate it.